# c++ test if random number is positive or negative

Tags: c++

I have school work with C++ and Im new to it. I have to generate 17 random numbers and then test if they are positive/negative/equal to zero. I can't seem to find a way to take the random generated number from the for loop to test it in the if/else if loop. Heeeeelp please :D (The b variable is just there from tests)

```
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    srand(
          (unsigned) time(0)
    );

    int a;
    int b;
    int num;

    for(int a = 0; a<17; a++) {
        cout << "Skaitlis: " << rand()% 20 + -10 << "\n";

        if(b > 0){
            cout << b << " is a positive number." << endl;
        }
        else if (b == 0){
            cout << b << " is equal to zero." << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << b << " is a negative number." << endl;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Use a variable.

Comment: You never give `b` a value, so how could it reliably compare to anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy enough, first assign the value to b, so you can then compare it. The current cout just outputs it.

```
b = rand()% 20 - 10;
cout << "Skaitlis: " << b << "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your variable `b` has no value at all. In your loop, you are asking 17 times if `b` is greater, lesser or equal to 0, where is your problem.

You have never never assigned to `b`. You will fix it by adding
`b = rand() % 20 + -10` inside your loop. Now your `b` has an actual value.

Also, instead of

`cout << "Skaitlis: " << rand()% 20 + -10 << "\n";`,

change to

`cout << "Skaitlis: " << b << endl;`.

Also, your `cout` doensn't exist since it's never declared. What I want to say is that you don't have `cout` function in your program because `cout` is found in "iostream" library. You have to include "iostream" library as well, with `#include <iostream>` at the start of the code.

**To clarify:**

Your `b` has no value. Assign a value to `b` before asking if it's greater, lesser or equal to 0;

`cout` is not added in your program. Include "iostream" with `#include <iostream>`

Final code can look like:

```cpp
#include <iostream> // so I can use cout << and cin >>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
  int b;
  srand(time(NULL)); // NULL is same as 0

  for (int a = 0; a < 17; a++) {
    b = rand() % 21 - 10; // Assign a value between -10 and +10 to b

    if (b > 0) cout << b << "is greater than 0" << endl;

    else if (b < 0) cout << b << "is lower than 0" << endl;

    else cout << b << "is equal to 0" << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I hope this explanation helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
#include <random>
void function(){
std::random_device rd; // obtain a random number from hardware
std::mt19937 gen(rd()); // seed the generator
std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(-100, 100); // define the range
int randomNumber = distr(gen);
if(randomNumber > 0)
    // bigger than 0
else if(randomNumber == 0)
    // equals 0
else
    // less than 0
}
```

Comment: Even though you provide a good suggestion, you don't really address the problem of the OP; at least you do not explain what you did to fix the issue the OP is referring to.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it's obvious.

Comment: It is obvious to us, but not to the OP. Also you added other stuff that really isn't necessary or even desires for the OP's program.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you mean, but you can just assign the result of your random function to a variable, for example:

```cpp
int rnd = rand() % 20 - 10;
cout << "Skaitlis: " << rnd << '\n';
if (rnd > 0)
    cout << rnd << " is a positive number." << endl;
else if (rnd == 0)
    cout << rnd << " is equal to zero." << endl;
else 
    cout << rnd << " is a negative number." << endl;
```

Also, if you are just starting programming, I don't think that's necessary to know, but keep in mind that `rand()` isn't really a good way to create random numbers. It's way better to use for example `mt19937` (although it's a little bit more complicated). `rand()` function generates random numbers only up to 32767 (though it also depends on the compilator you're using) and if you're trying to get a random number in a specific range, there's also a higher chance , that the `rand()` function will return a smaller number.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool is_positive(int number)
{
    if (number >= 0) return true; // Positive number or 0
    else return false; // Negative number
}

int main()
{
    std::srand(time(0));

    for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
    {
        int number = std::rand() % 20 + -10;

        if (is_positive(number))
        {
            std::cout << number << " is positive" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << number << " is negative" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Here I have defined a function is_positive that returns true if the number is greater than or equal to 0 else it returns false. I have also shown a simple implementation of the function.